# Back-reference when preprend using sed linux command

Tags: regex, linux, sed, prepend, backreference

I'm trying to prepend the first character of "monkey" using this command:

```
echo monkey | sed -E '/(.)onkey/i \1'
```

But when I use it like this, the output shows

```
1
monkey
```

I actually hope to see:

```
m
monkey
```

But back-reference doesn't work. Please someone tell me if it is possible to use Back-reference with \1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Backreferences only exist [within a regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html#index-back_002dreference) or [in the replacement part of the `s///` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#index-Backreferences_002c-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
echo 'monkey' | sed -E 's/(.)onkey/\1\n&/'

m
monkey
```

Here:

- `\1`: is back-reference for group #1
- `\n`: inserts a line break
- `&`:  is back-reference for full match

Answer (score 2):

With any version of `awk` you can try following solution, written and tested with shown samples. Simply searching regex `^.onkey` and then using `sub` function to substitute starting letter with itself new line and itself and printing the value(s).

```bash
echo monkey | awk '/^.onkey/{sub(/^./,"&\n&")} 1'
```

Comment: `/^./` will match any starting char not just `monkey`

Comment: @anubhava, sure sir fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/monkey/i m' file
```

Insert the line containing `m` only above a line containing `monkey`.

Perhaps a more generic solution would be to insert the first character of a word above that word:

```
sed -E 'h;s/\B.*//;G' file
```

Make copy of the word.

Remove all but the first character of the word.

Append the original word delimited by a newline.

Print the result.

N.B. `\B` starts a match between characters of a word. `\b` represents the start or end of a word (as does `\<` and `\>` separately).